# Change U-Boot Environment Variable in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, u-boot

I want to change u-boot environment variables in Linux via `fw_setenv` command. When i try to print environment variables via `fw_printenv` there is no error or warning, it works fine. However, when I try to change these variables I got an error: "Can't open /dev/mtd4: Permission denied". Here my settings:

In DTS:

```
nor@0,0 {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    compatible = "cfi-flash";
    reg=<0x0 0x0 0x1000000>;
    bank-width = <2>;
    device-width = <1>;

    partition@0 {
        /* This location must not be altered  */
        /* 256KB for Vitesse 7385 Switch firmware */
        reg=<0x0 0x00040000>;
        label="NOR Vitesse-7385 Firmware";
        read-only;
    };

    partition@40000 {
        /* 256KB for DTB Image */
        reg=<0x00040000 0x00040000>;
        label = "NOR DTB Image";
    };

    partition@80000 {
        /* 3.5 MB for Linux Kernel Image */
        reg = <0x00080000 0x00380000>;
        label = "NOR Linux Kernel Image";
    };

    partition@400000 {
        /* 11MB for JFFS2 based Root file System */
        reg=<0x00400000 0x00b00000>;
        label = "NOR JFFS2 Root File System";
    };

    partition@f20000 {
        /* 8KB for u-boot Environment Variables */
        reg=<0x00f20000 0x00002000>;
        label = "NOR U-Boot Environment Variable";
    };

    partition@f40000 {
        /* This location must not be altered  */
        /* 512KB for u-boot Bootloader Image */
        reg=<0x00f40000 0x000C0000>;
        label = "NOR U-Boot Image";
    };
```

};

In Linux:

```
mtd0: 00040000 00020000 "NOR Vitesse-7385 Firmware"
mtd1: 00040000 00020000 "NOR DTB Image"
mtd2: 00380000 00020000 "NOR Linux Kernel Image"
mtd3: 00b00000 00020000 "NOR JFFS2 Root File System"
mtd4: 00002000 00020000 "NOR U-Boot Environment Variable"
mtd5: 000c0000 00020000 "NOR U-Boot Image"
```

What is wrong in these configurations?
Thanks for the help..

Comment: `ls -l /dev/mtd4`? `cat /sys/class/mtd/mtd4/flags`? Did you try `flash_unlock /dev/mtd4` (or `mtd unlock ...`)?

Comment: ls -l gives crw------              
flash_unlock gives error 13: permssion denied, flags: 0x2800

Comment: `flags: 0x2800` [means](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-mtd) flash is not recognized as writable. Any warnings in dmesg regarding mtd4, e.g. `mtd: partition "..." doesn't start on an erase/write block boundary`? What are write/erase block sizes?

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This seems to be a question about system configuration, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [unix.se]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.

Comment: /etc/fw_env.config: /dev/mtd4 0x00 0x2000 0x20000. And there is no warning message in dmesg.

Answer (score 1):

```
mtd4: 00002000 00020000 "NOR U-Boot Environment Variable"
```

Partition size is 8 kb but flash erasesize is 128 kb. Partition must start and end on erase/write block boundary to be writeable.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have changed dts file to                            
   `partition@f20000 {
        /* 8KB for u-boot Environment Variables */
        reg=<0x00f20000 0x00020000>;
        label = "NOR U-Boot Environment Variable";
    };  ` and it's working.